# Explode a string that contains the route to a file to changes the filename and reconstruct the route

Tags: php

I've a backend that the user selects the route of the file, and I've an input like:

```
/images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/image_example.jpg
```

Then, with my PHP application I need to change that "image_example" because I encode the name for prevent problems. I split the file name with the last "." to seperate name from extension and then I return the new image name and extension... but I don't know how to identify the route, separate the name, and then rewrite the route.

So the worflow will be like:

1. User inputs the route.
2. The application identifies the image name.
3. I call a function than changes the name.
4. Reconstruct the rotue for the final copy/move.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is cryptic. What result do you want? Move existing files and get the path to the new filename?

Comment: not too good with regular expressions, but seems to me the simplest way is to find all characters that exist between '/' and '.', without an additional '/'

Comment: Sorry for explanation, English is not my main language. Basically I've a input like `/images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/image_example.jpg` and I've to change the image name to another, and finally get something like: `/images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/CHANGEDNAME_SAMEROUTE.jpg`. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PHP's [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function to split a file path into it's components. Like this:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/image_example.jpg');
```

The resulting array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => /images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match
    [basename] => image_example.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [filename] => image_example
)
```

With these informations you can then put together your new path:

```
$new_path = $path_parts['dirname'] . '/CHANGEDNAME_SAMEROUTE.' .
        $path_parts['extension'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to accomplish?

```
$sImageLocation = "/images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/image_example.jpg";
$sPath = substr($sImageLocation, 0, strrpos($sImageLocation, "/")+1);
$sNewImageLocation = $sPath."image_new.jpg";

echo $sNewImageLocation; 
// will output: /images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/image_new.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the line of this:

```
$route = '/images/soccer/2010-2011/last_match/image_example.jpg';
preg_match('/^(.*?\/)([^.\/]*)(\.[a-z]*)$/', $route, $matches);
$route[1] = your_function($route[1]);
$route = implode($matches);
```

First it takes apart your route with a regular expression, applies your function to the filename part of the route and then reassembles it.

(The regular expression might not be the best option, but I think it does the job.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the last part of the route/url, then this might be the laziest option:

```
$route = preg_replace("#(?<=/)\w+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|webp)$#",
                      "NEWNAME.$1", $route);
```

If the filename can contain other symbols than letters/numbers/underscores, then use `[^/]+` instead of `\w+`. Also adapt the list of acceptable extensions if you must.